# Cannot compile (Not declared & Expected Primary Expression)

Tags: c++, mysql, regex, struct

So bellow follows a function that will then be called for a main program. My problem is, if I do not declare challInfo as a struct, upon compiling, it will return:

> ERROR on page PhotoPoints at line 5, col 21: ‘challInfo’ was not declared in this scope

Meanwhile, if I do declare it (as it is bellow) it returns:

> ERROR on page PhotoPoints at line 5, col 30: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token ERROR on page PhotoPoints at line 7, col 52: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token ERROR on page PhotoPoints at line 8, col 28: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token ERROR on page PhotoPoints at line 8, col 60: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token ERROR on page PhotoPoints at line 8, col 109: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token ERROR on page PhotoPoints at line 9, col 31: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token ERROR on page PhotoPoints at line 9, col 66: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token ERROR on page PhotoPoints at line 9, col 118: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token ERROR on page PhotoPoints at line 14, col 35: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token ERROR on page PhotoPoints at line 14, col 57: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

I have been looking around the internet, including Stack Overflow, and it always seems the answer to this is specific to each case. I admit I'm lost. Can you help?

```
float PhotoPoints() {
struct challInfo; 
  bool isFacingOther();
  bool sphereInDark();
  bool isCameraOn = challInfo.camera.cameraOn;
  bool isFacingOtherResult = isFacingOther();
  bool isOppNotInDarkZone = !sphereInDark(challInfo.other.zrState);
  bool myMirror = challInfo.me.mirrorTime != 0 && challInfo.me.mirrorTime + ITEM_MIRROR_DURATION > challInfo.currentTime;
  bool otherMirror = challInfo.other.mirrorTime != 0 && challInfo.other.mirrorTime + ITEM_MIRROR_DURATION > challInfo.currentTime;
  float picturePointValue = 0;
  if (isCameraOn && isFacingOtherResult && isOppNotInDarkZone && !myMirror)
  {
    float bet[3], distance;
    mathVecSubtract(bet, challInfo.me.zrState, challInfo.other.zrState, 3);
    distance = mathVecMagnitude(bet, 3);

    if (distance < PHOTO_MIN_DISTANCE) {
      DEBUG(("Not a good shot: too close to the other satellite | "));
      return 0.0;
    }
    picturePointValue = 2.0 + 0.1/(distance - PHOTO_MIN_DISTANCE + 0.1);
    if(otherMirror){
      picturePointValue = 0;
      DEBUG(("Not a good shot: Opposing mirror active |"));
    }

  }
  else if(!isCameraOn){
    DEBUG(("Not a good shot: camera off |"));
  }
  else if(myMirror){
    DEBUG(("Not a good shot: my mirror's in the way |"));
  }
  else if(!isFacingOtherResult) {
        DEBUG(("Not a good shot: not facing the other satellite | "));
    }
  else if(!isOppNotInDarkZone){
    DEBUG(("Not a good shot: opponent in dark zone |"));
  }
  return picturePointValue;
}
```

Comment: The `struct challInfo` seems to be missing a type name. Or, if `challInfo` is a struct type, it's missing both a variable name and a definition of the struct.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow, how would you correct it?

Comment: It's impossible for anyone else to guess how to correct it, but I would suspect that the function is supposed to have a parameter called "challInfo" of whatever type it is supposed to be.

Comment: Have you accepted an answer? @NunoViegas

Comment: Please remove 'mysql' tag; it seems to be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here for every time you have referenced a member of `challInfo`. You need to include a full declaration so that the compiler can tell what is inside of the struct, nut simply that it is a struct. You have only provided a forward declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct challInfo;
```

Should have a definition like:

```
// Define your camera object
struct Camera {
        bool isCameraOn;
}
// Define the object type of challInfo
struct PhotographyInfo {
   Camera camera
}
```

then you can use the object:

```
PhotographyInfo challInfo{};
challInfo.camera = Camera{true};
```

Answer (score 0):

you define a `struct challInfo` then after assign the `bool isCameraOn` to a data member of that `struct`. Here is the problem I think you are a bit confused about `structs`. A `struct` is in many ways like a class. Where for example I could put something like this in a header file with other class definitions.

```
struct Example_struct{
      int data_mem_a;
      bool data_mem_b;
}
```

Then perhaps use this `struct` in a `class` prototype

```
class example_class{
private:
    example_struct struct_instance;
public:
    bool get_a_from_struct(){return struct_instance.data_mem_a;};
```

In your case you would want to make sure that the `challInfo` struct is defined somewhere, and then declare an instance of it.

```
 challInfo CI;
 bool isCameraOn = CI.camera.caneraOn;
```